# Why do we need to render components in a different root DOM?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was reading react documentation, state and lifecycle specifically at https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html. Under Converting a Function to a Class topic, it has ***"The render method will be called each time an update happens, but as long as we render  into the same DOM node, only a single instance of the Clock class will be used. This lets us use additional features such as local state and lifecycle methods."***

I was thinking if we can render few components into different DOM node. And I came across this medium article on conditional rendering a component in a different DOM node. https://medium.com/@theonlyrao/rendering-components-in-different-dom-elements-with-react-343533dd7eef

In real time scenario, when would we need this?

Answer (score 0):

That article is from 2016.

You can freely mount as many component instances as you like into different DOM nodes.

Assuming HTML that looks like

```html
<div id="a" />
<div id="b" />
```

and code like

```
// Simple React component.
const Greeter = ({name}) => <h1>Hello, {name}!</h1>;

// Mounting code.
ReactDOM.render(<Greeter name="Alice" />, document.getElementById("a"));
ReactDOM.render(<Greeter name="Bob" />, document.getElementById("b"));
```

things will work just fine. The two components are independent of each other.